# XSS "Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame" error in content script for a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xss

I've had this extension in the Google Chrome store for a while now. After doing a maintenance update I noticed that the following line from the `content.js` (content script):

```
//Get top document URL (that is the same for all IFRAMEs)
var strTopURL = window.top.document.URL;
```

is now throwing the following exception when the loaded page has an `IFRAME` in it:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame.

Like I said, it used to be the way to obtain the top document URL for your extension (from the `content script`). So what's the accepted way to do it now?

PS. Again, I'm talking about a Google Chrome extension (and not just a regular JS on the page.)

**EDIT:** This script is running under the `content_scripts` in the `manifest.json` that is defined as such:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames" : true,
        "match_about_blank": true,
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
],
```

Comment: Google changed a lot of stuff relating to permissions and it is not a simple change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content script should ask your background script to do it via messaging:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('getTopUrl', url => {
  // use the URL here inside the callback or store in a global variable
  // to use in another event callback that will be triggered in the future
  console.log(url);
});
// can't use it right here - because the callback runs asynchronously
```

The [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) should be declared in manifest.json:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
```

You'll also need need specific URL permissions in manifest.json or allow all URLs:

```
"permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
```

And the listener in the background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg === 'getTopUrl') {
    chrome.tabs.get(sender.tab.id, tab => sendResponse(tab.url));
    // keep the message channel open for the asynchronous callback above
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm. That's a lot of changes. I was wondering if I can use `document.referrer` instead?

Comment: Plus, I'm not needing it for the `background` script. I'm calling it from the `.js` script running under `content_scripts` in the manifest. (I'll update the question with details.)

Comment: Referrer may be absent and your iframe may be deeper than second level. As for the second objection I didn't understand what is the problem, I don't see it as such.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess I should try if it also works in the `content.js` vs your suggested `background.js`. (If I remember correctly they were running under different permissions.)

Comment: chrome.tabs is not available in a content script, which is why you need a background script. I still don't see why is that a problem.

Comment: The idea in short is that your content script asks the background script.